# Automate the Import Data form (.isy - SharePoint)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

So I've automated IE to `.click` 'Export to Excel' on SharePoint in a new Excel Workbook (for security our organisation has disabled Visual Basic for SharePoint).

I have used `.SendKeys` to interact with the first message box and used some nasty settings to shut the data connections security warning up.

That just leaves the Import Data form to deal with:

[image: The hurdle]

When I try to use `.SendKeys` to imitate Return or Spacebar, the keypress is happening elsewhere, whether in my code when developer is open or in another application when it is not.

I have tried to select Sheet1 as if I was to do this manually the form would gain focus.

Any ideas how I can automate control of this form or force it to gain focus so that `.SendKeys` will work?

For clarity, here's my full code:

```
Sub export()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = Nothing

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.Navigate "SITE CANNOT BE DISCLOSED"

    Do Until (IE.readystate = 4 And Not IE.Busy)
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim list

    Set list = IE.Document.getElementById("Ribbon.List-Title").getElementsByTagName("a")(0)

    list.Click
    'list.FireEvent ("onclick") alternative

    Do Until (IE.readystate = 4 And Not IE.Busy)
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim export

    Set export = IE.Document.getElementById("Ribbon.List.Actions.ExportToSpreadsheet-Large")
    export.Click

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Application.SendKeys "%{O}" 'works up to here need to make focus change before next keypress

    Workbooks("Reporting Macro").Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Application.SendKeys " "

    End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` perhaps?

Comment: That's already in the `With Application` bit :)

Comment: My apologies, shouldn't answer off the top of my head! :o)

Comment: No problem, I had that epiphany myself and was gutted to see it didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't even need to macro the .isy download / import, I can simply refresh the data connection as part of my macro.

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```